# How to get photo Like Info from graph explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Can any body tell me how to get the photo Like Info from graph explorer?I tried this fql query

```
select like_info from photo where object_id=PHOTO ID
```

Using this query This photo Id-**10152460216420695** gives me result

```
{
"data": [
  {
    "like_info": {
    "can_like": true,
    "like_count": 2118,
    "user_likes": false
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But this photo Id-**551468638224054** gives me result

```
{
 "data": [
   ]
}
```

This two photo are the public and both have more than 1 like.So why the last one can not give me the right result?Waiting for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
select like_info from photo where object_id="PHOTO ID"
```

If it fails than it means The photo is invisible for graph api.

Comment: You did not read my whole question.I used this method which did not work before.But this is working now so i accept your answer.

Comment: I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

One of those photos may not be available via the API due to privacy settings. Even though a photo is public on Facebook itself, there may be other reasons why the piece of content isn't emitted via the API.

Comment: But sir,i saw another website has got the like info of the second photo Using facebook app.Is my application is weak?